# Can I have a template on an instance method in CPP?

Tags: c++

I want to do the following (unless there's just a better way that's more C++-ey)

```
class A
{
...
   template<typename T>
   <const T> methodName(args);
}
```

So I can use it as following:

```
A myObj;
myObj->methodName<myTypeName>(args);
```

But this isn't the syntax of the method call.

What's the correct way to write this? For some details the code is intended to consume a message type for which the object holds the raw data. The raw data is then decoded according to the message type and the data is stored on the object.

Comment: That almost looks right, except you don't put the return type in angled brackets `<>` and you need to specify the type(s) of `args`. You also don't use the dereference-and-access operator `->` because `myObj` isn't a pointer, so the calling code would just be `myObj.methodName<myTypeName>(args);`

Comment: That seems right to me, except remove the <> around const T

Comment: Assuming you've removed the `<>` around `const T` ......   if `myObj` is an `A` then `myObj->methodName<myTypeName>(args);` won't work, but `myObj.methodName<myTypeName>(args);`  will.    You could do a little hackery with an `operator->()` member function to get `myObj-> ...` working, but that would be a *terrible* approach.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the correct way to write this?

You have surrounded `const T` with angle brackets `<>` which is not needed. Moreover, you've used `->` instead of using `.` when calling the member function.

```
class A
{
public:
//----------------------vvvvvvv--------------------->angle brackets removed from around const T
   template<typename T> const T methodName(T arg)
   {
       std::cout<<"methodName called"<<std::endl;
       return arg;
   }
};
int main()
{
    A myObj;
//-------v---------------------->used . instead of ->
    myObj.methodName<int>(4);
//------------------v------->no need for <double> here as template argument deduction can be used automatically
    myObj.methodName(5.5); 

    
    return 0;
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/hfMOvT1cp)